# Repeat Alarm in day time only

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to remind user about their tablets to be intaken at specific interval in day time only.
I know how the notification and alram manager works. But don't know how can I solve my above mentioned problem. Sometimes in between I need to stop/cancel that repeating alarm.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

regds,
Pratheeja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PendingIntent you fire to reset the alarm every time it goes off by adding a new alarm in 24 hours.
Don't forget to add a BroadcastReceiver that receives device boot action (`android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`) as alarms get deleted on device boot and you would have to reset the alarm to the remaining time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now am using pending intent for notifying user.  Actually I need to remind user only at day time like before food/after food and it will be for 2 to 3 days. How can I block that alarm service for night time?

Comment: Define daytime... Simply use the current time of the device and set an alarm to the difference until, let's say, 10am... Although a better option is to allow the user to set the accurate time he/she wants the reminder